# Django Rest - testing api delete

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Currrently I am testing my django rest api, but I am stuck on delete method.

My url looks like this

```
  path('books/shelfs/<int:shelf>/readers/<int:pk>/',
    views.ReaderViewSet.as_view(
        {'get': 'retrieve', 'delete': 'destroy', 'patch': 'partial_update'}),
```

And My ViewSets looks like this

```
  def destroy(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.data.get("book_type") is None:
        raise ParseError(detail="book_type is required, options are : 'global, non-global'")
    try:
        instance = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_object())
        .......
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
    except Http404:
        pass
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And my test case is this

```
   def test_book_delete(self):
   
    # check if delete works
    book_type = {'book_type': 'global'}

    response = self.client.delete("/api/v1/books/shelfs/{}/"
                                  "readers/{}/".format(
                                      1, 2), data=book_type)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 204)
```

But its alway 415 error

The question is, how to pass this `book_type` in delete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP [415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) means that the server refused to accept the JSON payload.

[Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#explicitly-encoding-the-request-body):

> If you need to explicitly encode the request body, you can do so by setting the content_type flag.

So try to set the `content_type` as follows:

```py
response = self.client.delete("/api/v1/books/shelfs/{}/"
                                  "readers/{}/".format(
                                      1, 2), data=book_type, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: ok - so there is no resource to delete at `/api/v1/books/shelfs/1/readers/2/`

Comment: it actually exists. it works well but I need to add custom data in request for some checking so thats why I need to add some data in request body, without those extra requirements it just work, so maybe Django Rest  not designed to add body in delete method, I am not sure need to read the docs

Comment: am in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223872/64607476) - will help if I can

Comment: So I already know exactly where the error came from.Thanks for your help